# Method must have a value return type... though it has one already

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a class that contains a header for my list-box. I have two classes that I will be inserting in the listbox. The first class runs fine, but the second one I am making so that the array is entirely of strings is telling me that a method must have a value return type. What does this mean exactly? The error at hand is "HeaderItems."

```
namespace RETAILITEMSBLAKE
{
class HeaderClass
{
    string HeaderDescription;
    string HeaderPrice;
    string HeaderUnitsonHand;

    public HeaderItems(string HeaderDescription, string HeaderUnitsonHand, string HeaderPrice)
    {
        this.HeaderDescription = HeaderDescription;
        this.HeaderUnitsonHand = HeaderUnitsonHand;
        this.HeaderPrice = HeaderPrice;
    }

    public string HeaderDescriptions
    {
        get
        {
            return HeaderDescription;
        }
        set
        {
            HeaderDescription = value;
        }
    }
    public string HeaderUnits
    {
        get
        {
            return HeaderUnitsonHand;
        }
        set
        {
            HeaderUnitsonHand = value;
        }
    }
    public string HeaderPrices
    {
        get
        {
            return HeaderPrice;
        }
        set
        {
            HeaderPrice = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my first class that is working correctly:

```
    namespace RETAILitemsBLAKE
 {
    class ItemizedClass
   {

    string description;
    int unitsonhand;
    double price;

    public ItemizedClass(string description,int unitsonhand,double price)
    {
        this.description = description;
        this.unitsonhand = unitsonhand;
        this.price = price;

    }



    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return description;
        }
        set
        {
            description = value;
        }
    }
    public double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
        set
        {
            price = value;
        }
    }
    public int Quantity
    {
        get
        {
            return unitsonhand;
        }
        set
        {
            unitsonhand = value;
        }
    }
}
}
```

So, my goal is to have the HeaderClass so that I can place them as headers in my Listbox. Is there an alternate way to do such? I want to place it on top of the code here:

```
   namespace RETAILitemsBLAKE
     {
       public partial class FrmItemList : Form
{

    ItemizedClass[] items;

    public FrmItemList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ItemizedArray();
    }
    private void ItemizedArray()
    {


        ItemizedClass jackets = new ItemizedClass("Jackets", 12, 59.95);
        ItemizedClass jeans = new ItemizedClass("Jeans", 40, 34.95);
        ItemizedClass shirts = new ItemizedClass("Shirts", 20, 24.95);

        items = new ItemizedClass[] { jackets, jeans, shirts };

        foreach (ItemizedClass RetailData in items)
        {
            lstRetailitems.Items.Add(RetailData.Description + "\t\t" + RetailData.Quantity + "\t" + "$" + RetailData.Price);


        }




    }
}
  }
```

Would anyone be of assistance? Thank you!

Comment: `though it has one already` What is the return type of that method? What is the name of that method?

Comment: Either have the `HeaderItems` method return `void`, or give it the same name as the class (so it becomes a constructor, which doesn't have a return type). Also, FWIW, namespaces are case-sensitive, so the `HeaderClass` in you all-caps namespace (ick!) will not be automatically discoverable in your mixed-all-caps-lowercase namespace (double ick!).  I only say "ick" because the convention for namespaces is PascalCase, like: `namespace RetailItemsBlake`.

Comment: @RufusL is that why you think it is not being detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using construct method which needs as same as class name and it didn't need to set return data type, so the method name needs to write `HeaderClass` in `HeaderClass` class otherwise it needs to set return data type to be a normal method.

```
class HeaderClass
{
    string HeaderDescription;
    string HeaderPrice;
    string HeaderUnitsonHand;

    public HeaderClass(string HeaderDescription, string HeaderUnitsonHand, string HeaderPrice)
```

Comment: Thank you! When I try to turn this class into an array, the form says it cannot be recognized. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean `turn this class into an array,` which array?

Comment: My class is not being recognized at all when trying to use it in the main code.

Comment: Did you want to let `RetailData.Description + "\t\t" + RetailData.Quantity + "\t" + "$" + RetailData.Price` init for the mehtod and return a string?

Comment: No. Perhaps I do not know arrays correctly. What I want to do is add headers on the listbox that would be above the contents displayed. When I try to use the same class to do so, I get errors such as "String cannot convert to int" which is why I am trying to create a new class. String cannot convert to int because the array is set for the Price to be an int.

Comment: You can try to use `ToString` method  `RetailData.Description + "\t\t" + RetailData.Quantity.ToString() + "\t" + "$" + RetailData.Price.ToString()` let int to string value.

Comment: Does not work. To clarify, I cannot use the same class. I want to create a new row that is specifically for "String" because using the same class results in the "cannot convert" because the class is specifically made for integers in the second row, etc if you refer to how the jeans and jackets are set up. Imagine a table in a listbox, I want the headers on top.

Comment: if you want to use `ItemizedClass `  set content and title you need to let `double Price` and   `public int Quantity` properties to be a string value, and accept `string` in construct method.

Comment: Will this let integer numbers work either way? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Or you can just use `HeaderClass Headers = new HeaderClass("Description", "Units on Hand", "Price");` instead of `ItemizedClass Headers = new ItemizedClass("Description", "Units on Hand", "Price");`

Comment: The HeaderClass cannot be detected in the Namespace is my issue. That is my entire problem at the moment.

Comment: Fixed! I let visual studio create the file for me and pasted my code. Odd.